# How can I use jQuery to toggle between 2 classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not sure toggleClass is the best way to do this, but I have a accordion menu and I am attempting to alternate the icon/image on the right side from a RIGHT arrow to a DOWN arrow.

The first click on the 3 menu items shows the DOWN image (.icon-03) but when I switch between the accordion items it does not go back to the RIGHT arrow image/class (.icon-04).
thoughts?

```
/* Accordion */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#accordionFAQ > li > a').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#accordionFAQ li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#accordionFAQ li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      //add down arrow
      $('> span', this).toggleClass('icon-03 icon-04');

      //prevent page reload
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Demo JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/957Fs/

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI?

Comment: I am not, see link in revision @FastTrack

Comment: Does the span have a c3 or c4 class to start? Otherwise it might be adding them both and taking them away again together.

Comment: don't link to external site as that url will likley be different in the future...provide live demo in jsfiddle.net that allows people to interact with code to help find solutions

Comment: Look at the first line of your handler: `if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){`. When you click on the link, it adds the active class, so the next time you click that condition fails and nothing changes.

Comment: It starts with class03 @Chad

Comment: ahh, I have to take it outside of this function? What is a fast/LESS way of refactoring that? @Mathletics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `$(this).attr('class') != 'active'` is very inefficient (and possibly fails to work altogether), use `$(this).hasClass('active')` instead.

After your comment, I re-added the classes - the following should work:

```
$('#accordionFAQ > li > a').click(function(e){
   if (! $(this).hasClass('active') ){
       $('.active')
           .find('span').toggleClass('icon-03 icon-04')
           .end().removeClass('active')
           .next().slideUp();
       $(this).find('span').toggleClass('icon-03 icon-04')
           .end().addClass('active')
           .next().slideDown();
       //prevent page reload
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: How is this an answer?  This is a couple coding suggestions, but not an answer to the question for why it doesn't work.

Comment: @jfriend00 this is an answer because if the OP implements it this way it's easier AND it works.

Comment: This fails to address the problem that, once the link has the active class, it does nothing (which is the OPs actual question.)

Comment: @Mathletics well, either you misread the question or my answer. It does exactly what OP wants - recovering the old item once you click another accordion item.

Comment: Is this a joke? Did you test this?

Comment: Needed a bit of testing/fine tuning Mathletics but I get where he was coming from. The JS was off a bit and I have to edit my html markup for the better with less code: http://jsfiddle.net/957Fs/10/ Thanks @Cristoph

Comment: Noticed you changed your answer, I would revert back otherwise my new fiddle makes no sense :D @Christoph

Comment: @KevinOrin You are welcome, I just took a quick look at your code - feel free to edit my answer to contain the correct code.

Comment: @Mathletics can you tell me, why you are hating so much? I have no problem with constructive criticism, but what you do is far from being constructive...

Comment: @Christoph sorry :-[ sometimes my afternoon comments come off meaner than I intend.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the JSFiddle example it works for me, so I guess it's updated already. I'd like to make a suggestion though: it's perhaps a good idea to just toggle a class (e.g. 'is-active') on your list items and handle the rest with pure CSS. For example:

```
var $faq = $('#accordionFAQ');
$faq.on('click', '> li > a', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

In your CSS you could do something like this:

```
#accordionFAQ > li > a span {
  // width, height etc
  background-position: x y;
}
#accordionFAQ > li.is-active > a span {
  background-position: x y;
 }
```

Just an idea; hope it's helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Accordion */
$(document).ready(function () {
  var accordionFAQ = $('#accordionFAQ');

  // let's use jQuery's .on() rather than .click()
  accordionFAQ.find('a').on({

    click:function(e){

      // prevent the default action
      e.preventDefault();

      // setup some variables
      var that = $(this);

      // close open ULs
      accordionFAQ.find('ul').slideUp();

      // remove .active from other controller
      accordionFAQ.find('.active').removeClass('active');

      // add .active to clicked controller and show UL
      that.addClass('active').next().slideDown();

      // remove .right from span
      accordionFAQ.find('.right').removeClass('right');

      // add .right to current controller's span
      that.find('span').addClass('right');

    }

  });

});
```

Then, you can have span's default image be the left arrow. and when you add a .right class, it will override the default image with a right arrow using CSS.

hope this helps.